# Async notification when another application changes the database with entity framework 4.1 and DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a REST web service that is used for comunication with multiple clients, some sort of chat, but I have to make all the changes into the database as soon as the clients comunicate something and then inform all the others clients when a change is made.

I basically get a POST request and I have to reply as soon as an entry is mofified.

Now I make my thread sleep 1 second and then keep recreating the context every second for each request and if there are changes to the database I send the response. 
This looks ugly to me and I wonder if there is some event or async method to be notified when a specific entry in the database is modified?

Thank you Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MS SQL Server, you might have success with using Sql Dependencies.  Here's a link to a brief tutorial:  [C# & SqlDependency - Monitoring your database for data changes](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring).

Microsoft's successor to Notification Services, [SQL Server 2008 R2 – Complex Event Processing (CEP) Technology](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2-complex-event.aspx) might also serve your purposes, but I know nothing about it but what's on the web page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into those links. I'll try to combine the source from the first link with this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234085/Fixing-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-API